# How to get list of step siblings in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, family-tree

Following is my schema :-

```
postgres=# \d check_user;
                         Table "public.check_user"
 Column |  Type   |                        Modifiers
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('check_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | text    |
 gender | text    |
Indexes:
    "check_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "parent" CONSTRAINT "parent_left_node_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (left_node) REFERENCES check_user(id)
    TABLE "parent" CONSTRAINT "parent_right_node_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (right_node) REFERENCES check_user(id)
    TABLE "spouse" CONSTRAINT "spouse_husband_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (husband) REFERENCES check_user(id)
    TABLE "spouse" CONSTRAINT "spouse_wife_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (wife) REFERENCES check_user(id)


postgres=# \d parent;
                           Table "public.parent"
   Column   |  Type   |                      Modifiers
------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer | not null default nextval('parent_id_seq'::regclass)
 left_node  | integer |
 right_node | integer |
Indexes:
    "parent_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "parent_left_node_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (left_node) REFERENCES check_user(id)
    "parent_right_node_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (right_node) REFERENCES check_user(id)

postgres=# \d spouse
                          Table "public.spouse"
 Column  |  Type   |                      Modifiers
---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer | not null default nextval('spouse_id_seq'::regclass)
 husband | integer |
 wife    | integer |
Indexes:
    "spouse_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "spouse_husband_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (husband) REFERENCES check_user(id)
    "spouse_wife_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (wife) REFERENCES check_user(id)
```

Following is the data in each of these tables :-

```
postgres=# select * from check_user;
 id | name | gender
----+------+--------
  4 | a    | m
  1 | x    | m
  2 | y    | f
  3 | z    | f
  7 | c3   | f
  6 | c2   | m
  5 | c1   | m
  8 | b    | m
  9 | c4   | f
(9 rows)

postgres=# select * from spouse;
 id | husband | wife
----+---------+------
  1 |       1 |    2
  2 |       1 |    3
  3 |       4 |    2
  4 |       8 |    3
(4 rows)

postgres=# select * from parent;
 id | left_node | right_node
----+-----------+------------
  1 |         1 |          5
  2 |         2 |          5
  3 |         1 |          6
  4 |         3 |          6
  5 |         4 |          7
  6 |         2 |          7
  7 |         8 |          9
  8 |         3 |          9
```

Now, I want to find the step siblings of user c1. By step-siblings, I mean, users which are the son of either mother of father of c1, but not both.

I am using following query:-

```
 with user_parents as (
    select  child.id as child_id, child.name as child_name, parent_dtls.id as parent_id,
parent_dtls.name as parent_name, child.gender as child_gender, parent_dtls.gender as parent_gender
from check_user child
        inner join parent on child.id=parent.right_node
        inner join check_user parent_dtls on parent.left_node=parent_dtls.id
    ),
fathers as (select * from user_parents where user_parents.parent_gender='m'),
mothers as (select * from user_parents where user_parents.parent_gender='f'),
my_father as (select * from fathers where fathers.child_id=5),
my_mother as (select * from mothers where mothers.child_id=5)
select   user_.id as "user_id", fathers.parent_id as "father_id", my_father.parent_id "my_father_id",
mothers.parent_id as "mother_id", my_mother.parent_id as "my_mother_id" from parent parent_dtls
left join my_father on parent_dtls.left_node=my_father.parent_id
left join my_mother on parent_dtls.left_node=my_mother.parent_id
inner join check_user user_ on user_.id=parent_dtls.right_node
left join fathers on parent_dtls.right_node=fathers.child_id
left join mothers on parent_dtls.right_node=mothers.child_id where my_father.parent_id is null and my_mother.parent_id is null;
```

But I am getting other rows along with step-siblings.

What's wrong I am doing ? Moreover, please comment over the inefficiency if it's there in above query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See functions LAG and LEAD, as in this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53870/90651

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to solve the task step-by step. So the code is something like this:

`//select the child id
with child_id as (
select id from check_user where name = 'c1'),
//select parents ids
parents as (
select left_node, right_node from parent 
where id in (select * from child_id)
)
select * from check_user where id in (
   select id from parent where
//child of one parents, not both
    (left_node in 
       (select left_node from parents)
     and right_node not in
       (select right_node from parents))
      or (left_node not in (select left_node from parents)
     and right_node in (select right_node from parents)
     )
)`

p.s.
It looks like, the spouse table is unnecessary according to the task description.

Comment: See `LAG()` and `LEAD()` at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53870/90651